# How to navigate back to correct previous viewController

Tags: swift3, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have the following scenario:

```
            |---> VC1----->|
  VC_Home ->|---> VC2----->|------> VCm
            |---> VC3----->|
```

VC1, VC2 and VC3 can go to the same ViewController (VCm)

How to navigate back to the correct Previous VC from VCm
if I start from VC1 and go to VCm, then Vcm will return to VC1. 
So, the same for VC2  and VC3.

all VC1, VC2, VC3 dont embed with NavigationController.

will this be able to identify which is the previous page?

```
@IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any){
 navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `UINavigationController` in your `storyBoard`
2. Add new `UIViewController` [which is VC_HOME] and link it with `UINavigationController` as `root View Controller` (ctrl + drag)
3. Give it an ID (right utilities view -> Identity Inspector -> StoryBoard ID -> Name it "`myHome`")
4. Add 3 button [`go to vc1`, `go to vc2`, `go to vc3`] and of course add `@IBAction` for each of them
5. Add 3 different `UIViewController` for vc1, vc2, vc3 and like step 3  give them IDs `myVc1`, `myVc2`, `myVc3`

Now for `@IBAction go to vc1` add following code :

```
    let view = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVc1")     
navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

for `@IBAction go to vc2` add following code :

```
    let view = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVc2")     
navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

for `@IBAction go to vc3` add following code :

```
    let view = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVc3")     
navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

Now for each view add button go to `VC_M` like steps above

- for back to previous viewController [vc1, vc2, vc3] use this code :
  `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
- if you back to the root [VC_Home] use this : `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: How to navigate back from VCm to VC1 or VC2 or VC3.

Comment: By the code you mention it already in your question @MilkBottle

Comment: It didnot work. If I start with VC1 to VCm, it is ok from Vcm back to VC1. But in next, When I start from VC2 to VCm, it wont navigate to VC2. Why?

Answer (score 0):

just `dismiss` you final view controller. add following to you back action in your final view controller.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```